# C++ function `getline()` doesn't work correctly for char[]

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I need to extract the first 150 characters from a line and save them in a char[] array (no strings allowed). My code below doesn't work and i just can't find the reason why:

```cpp
#include <ifstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("message.txt");
    if(!myFile.is_open()) cout<<"error"; //added this after edit
    const int SIZE = 151;
    char buffer[SIZE]={};
    while(myFile.getline(buffer, 151)){
        buffer[150]='\0';
        cout<<buffer<<endl;
    }
    myFile.close();
}
```

Here's a snippet of "message.txt":

```html
abcdefg
hijklmn
opqrstuv
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
hello
```

It simply prints out nothing. The file "message.txt" exists and has several lines of characters in it. Where am I wrong?
EDIT: if the characters on a line are less than 150, they should all be read. If they are more than 150, the rest should be ignored.

Comment: You know the file opened successfully.. *how* ?

Comment: What happens if there are fewer than 150 characters in a line and there's a bunch of uninitialized garbage between the last character `getline` read and the null terminator you add at position 150?

Comment: Why bother with `char[]` in this case? I don't unless it needs to actually be a buffer, like reading in binary mode. This could work a lot easier with `std::string` and `std::getline()`.

Comment: I had an `if(!myFile.open()){cout<<"error";}` which didn't fire.

Comment: @NathanPierson If the characters are less than 150,  the program should read all of them and assign them to `buffer`; If the characters on a line are more than 150, the program should ignore the ones after the 150th and then proceed to the next line.

Comment: @sweenish This is part of a homework assignment so I can't choose.

Comment: To add on to Nathan's comment, you should be `memset`ing the entire array to be null characters, do the read, and still make sure you have at least one null character at the end of the string. C-strings are a pain unless you build a lot of code around them.

Comment: That seems like good desired behavior. Is that actually what's happening? Taking a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) I see that getline actually automatically places the null terminator for you. Could you please include a sample of `message.txt`?

Comment: @sweenish `char buffer[SIZE]={};` zero-initializes all elements.

Comment: Maybe the file is in the wrong folder or named incorrectly.

Comment: And `0` is not `\0`.

Comment: @sweenish added `memset(buffer, '\0', 151);` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanPierson It will set one for you, if it has room to do so. But with C-strings, the more that's explicit, the better. I do not trust them at all.

Comment: _I had an `if(!myFile.open()){cout<<"error";}`_ Did you leave the file name out on purpose? Also, try using the full path.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, I misspelled that. It is `!myFile.is_open()`. Sorry about that.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. All I did was change `#include <ifstream>` to `#include <fstream>` (assuming that was a typo creating the question and the actual code compiles!) and it works, including with the sample `message.txt`.

Comment: @NathanPierson I was working with CLion. I moved to Visual Studio and there it displayed all lines (FINALLY). Then I added "123" to the line with the 'a's and when I ran the code again, the program skipped that line (and the last one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to read the first 150 characters of the 1st line, then you don't need the `while` loop.  And you don't need to null-terminate the `buffer` manually, `istream::getline()` will do that for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <ifstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("message.txt");
    if (!myFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "error";
        return 0;
    }

    const int SIZE = 151;
    char buffer[SIZE] = {};
    myFile.getline(buffer, SIZE);

    cout << buffer << endl;

    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to read the first 150 characters *of a specific line only*, then you need a loop to skip all lines *regardless of their length* until you reach the desired line, and then you can read the 150 characters of just that line, eg:

```cpp
#include <ifstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("message.txt");
    if (!myFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "error";
        return 0;
    }

    size_t lineIndex = ...;
    while (lineIndex > 0)
    {
        if (!myFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'))
        {
            cout << "error";
            return 0;
        }

        if (myFile.eof())
        {
            cout << "eof";
            return 0;
        }

        --lineIndex;
    }

    const int SIZE = 151;
    char buffer[SIZE] = {};

    myFile.getline(buffer, SIZE);

    cout << buffer << endl;

    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to read the first 150 characters *of each line*, then after a successful read you need to skip any remaining characters prior to a line break before you can then read the next line, eg:

```cpp
#include <ifstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile("message.txt");
    if (!myFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "error";
        return 0;
    }

    const int SIZE = 151;
    char buffer[SIZE] = {};

    do
    {
        myFile.getline(buffer, SIZE);

        if (myFile.bad())
        {
            cout << "error";
            return 0;
        }

        if (myFile.fail())
        {
            // SIZE-1 characters were extracted before a line break
            // was reached, need to reset the error to keep going...
            myFile.clear();
            myFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        cout << buffer << endl;
    }
    while (!myFile.eof());

    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great! That read all lines except the last one and excluded all characters after the 150th. We are getting closer! What could be the reason for the program to stop before the last line?

Comment: @DanielHalachev you said it yourself - **excluded all characters after the 150th**. In the text file you provided, the `hello` line starts at the 181st character if using CRLF line breaks, or at the 177th character if using bare-CR or bare-LF line breaks. Both are well beyond the 150 char limit. So what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Oh, it seems I wasn't clear enough. I'd like the program to read up to 150 characters from _each_ line of the file. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DanielHalachev That is a very different requirement than what you posted originally.  I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been working on that problem for a week, hoping to find a single function that would do that and I asked several questions about trying to go around the problem. Again, thank you very much. The pain is finally over.